# How do I Filter Custom Post Type by Custom Taxonomy in the newest Wordpress RESTful API?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, wordpress-rest-api

I've a Custom Post Type called clock and a taxonomy called clock_category on my website.
It is working well and All the clocks can be accessed from the REST endpoint
https://myapp.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/clock

But I don't know how to filter them by the Clock category, say I want to get all the clocks which are made of wood

I tried different URLs but none of them seems to be working
https://myapp.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/clock?clock_category=wood
https://myapp.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/clock?clock_category=10

and many more. All I got was the full result set.

Here is the code

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'clock' );

function clock() {
    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( 'Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "singular_name" => __( 'clock', 'mywp' ),
        "menu_name" => __( 'Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "all_items" => __( 'All Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "add_new" => __( 'Add New Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "add_new_item" => __( 'Add New Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "edit_item" => __( 'Edit Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "new_item" => __( 'New Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "view_item" => __( 'View Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "search_items" => __( 'Search Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "not_found" => __( 'No Clock Found', 'mywp' ),
        "not_found_in_trash" => __( 'No Clock found in trash', 'mywp' ),
        "parent_item_colon" => __( 'Parent Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "featured_image" => __( 'Feature Image for Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "set_featured_image" => __( 'Set featured Clock image', 'mywp' ),
        "remove_featured_image" => __( 'Remove featured image for Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "use_featured_image" => __( 'Use featured image for Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "archives" => __( 'Clock archives', 'mywp' ),
        "insert_into_item" => __( 'Insert into Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "uploaded_to_this_item" => __( 'Uploaded to this Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "items_list_navigation" => __( 'Clock list navigation', 'mywp' ),
        "items_list" => __( 'Clock List', 'mywp' ),
        "parent_item_colon" => __( 'Parent Clock', 'mywp' ),
        );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( 'Clock', 'mywp' ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "Clock",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "clock",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
                "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "clock", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,

        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "custom-fields", "page-attributes", "post-formats" ),      
        "taxonomies" => array( ),
            );
    register_post_type( "clock", $args );
}


add_action( 'init', 'create_clock_tax' );

function create_clock_tax() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'clock_category',
        'clock',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Clock Category' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'clock_category' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Hope someone help me out on this. I've been trying to solve this for 5 hours and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Have you managed to get this work. I have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using the Backbone client? 
example:

```
var clock = new wp.api.models.Clock();
clock.fetch({data: {filter: {category: 'wood'}}})
     .done(function(d){
        //your code here...
     });
```

[Wordpress REST API reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/)